# How do you differentiate between "in order to", "so as to", "so that" and "to"?

Tags: phrases, differences, conjunctions, register, so-as-to

When we use the phrases *so as to*, *in order to*, and *so that*, we simply mean with the aim or
purpose of doing something. The first two phrases are always followed by an infinitive *to*.

Will I not be altering the meaning of the sentence, if I put both phrases *in order to/so as to* in one sentence, and also the phrase *so that* separately in another sentence? As in:

1. We took off our shoes **so as to/in order to** avoid scratching the newly finished floors.
2. We took off our shoes **so that** we can avoid scratching the newly finished floors.

Explicitly asking, which one of these phrases are informal and which one, not?

And is it okay to simply put the *to*-infinitive in written exams?

3. We took off our shoes **to** avoid scratching the newly finished floors.

Comment: There are some phrasings that are more awkward than others.  And sometimes the phrases are unneeded.  For instance, your example would be better as "We took off our shoes to avoid scratching the newly finished floors."

Comment: @HotLicks What about formality and informality of these phrases?

Comment: There is little difference in formality.  If anything, the wordier versions will "feel" less formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laboring under the distressingly common misapprehension that longer phrases 
are inherently “more formal” than shorter ones, many novice writers,
especially budding technical writers rather than polished writers of 
professional essays and fiction, will reflexively gravitate towards ever
longer and more sententious wordings.

At which point their copyeditors, should they be so lucky as to have such, 
will equally reflexively rewrite those “wordy” constructions into simpler
ones. For example:

1. so as to ᴠᴇʀʙ > to ᴠᴇʀʙ
2. in order to ᴠᴇʀʙ > to ᴠᴇʀʙ
3. so that > so

Note that this example of yours:

> We **took** off our shoes so that we ***can** avoid scratching the newly finished floors.

Has mismatched tenses: *took* is past tense but *can* is present tense. A happier sequence of tenses there would instead be the matched version shown here:

> We **took** off our shoes so that we **could** avoid scratching the newly finished floors.

But as you suspect, there’s no reason to use so heavy a wording when a lighter one will do just fine:

> - We took off our shoes to avoid scratching the newly finished floors.
> - We took our shoes off to avoid scratching the newly finished floors.

Comment: Sir, your answer is much helpful... Sir, may I join you on Facebook?