# so adjective as to-infinitive

Tags: adjectives, infinitives, so-as-to

I searched everywhere for an explanation about this construct but couldn't find.

The construct is: "so adjective as to-infinitive".
For example: "the kid was so brave as to amaze all his classmates."

I intuitively understand the meaning, but I avoid guessing as much as possible. Could someone please answer what is the meaning of that construct? Also, what's that sort of construct called?

Comment: Duplicate of [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/445927/2085), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/129570/2085), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/540272/2085), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/164090/2085), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/563031/2085), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/455811/2085). This is not an "idiom", and means exactly what it says it means.

Comment: "1" treats  "so as to", not "so [adjective] as  to". So  do "2", "3", "4", "5", and "6".

Answer (score 2):

Note that in your construct ***so*** also shows degree, extent:

> to an indicated or suggested extent or degree ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so))

In

> The kid was ***so*** *brave* ***as to*** *amaze* all his classmates.

the amazement of the classmates is in fact *the result/effect of the **degree*** of the kid's bravery.

There is negligible difference between your example (which is more formal) and the variant with ***that***

> The kid was ***so brave*** ***that*** all his classmates were amazed.

There are contexts, however, when the two constructs do differ. *[Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/10/so-as-so-that.html)* explains

> The difference is clearer when the consequence or result is more stark, as in
>
> > (1) The dose was ***so** large ***as to be*** fatal*.
>
> versus
>
> > (2) The dose was ***so** large **that** it was fatal*.
>
> #2 is the stronger statement. Why is this? Because the “so … as” constructions ***indicate extent or degree***, while the “so … that” constructions indicate ***an actual consequence—in other words, a theoretical versus a real result***.

To put it more clearly, (1) says that *the dose was so large that it **was able to bring/could have brought** death*, whereas (2) makes it real, saying that *the dose was so large that it provoked someone's death.*

Answer (score 1):

The structure is "[so...as](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/so)." It's an idiom, which is why you are having a tough time figuring out what it means, what with idioms having a meaning that differs from what the sum of their words convey literally. The idiom "[so...as](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/so)" is defined by [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/so) as:

> 29. so as,
>     a. with the result or purpose: to turn up the volume of the radio ***so as*** **to drown** out the noise from the next apartment.

The only difference between your example and the one given above is an adjective has been placed in between "so" and "as," as is often the case. That example given could just as well have been: "the volume of the radio was turned up ***so*** *loud* ***as*** **to drown** out the noise from the next apartment."

Comment: So the example "the kid was so brave as to amaze all his classmates"  means: the result of the kid's bravery was the classmates' amazement.

Comment: Yes, precisely. The amazement of his classmates was the result of his bravery, which may have resulted in other things, too, but if so, those aren't mentioned.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe it means: the purpose of the kid's bravery was the classmates' amazement.  I think "result" is more likely than "purpose", but we cannot tell from definition 29.

Comment: That's a possibility. How you would interpret it would depend on context. It's also worth mentioning that it's possible that the writer means both, is employing a double-entendre, that not only was their amazement the result of his bravery but also that the very reason he was so brave was for the purpose of amazing them, meaning he got the result that was he'd set to purpose.

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous. And yes, meaning both (or more) meanings is a standard technique in writing. Also, cause and effect are easy to mix up. The little words like _so, as, is, to, the, that,_ ... are the ones that cause all the trouble; they're just nuts and bolts, but you gotta put them in the right places or the machine stops.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Good point.

Comment: For me, this "so X as to [verb]" thing is *often*  used in lieu of  the more elegant: The kid was so brave that he [did x].

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say either way is "*more elegant*"-- beauty being in the eye of the beholder, there being more than one way to skin a cat, etc.

Comment: No, this is not an "idiom".

Comment: @tchrist - My citing it as an "idiom" is dictionary reference sourced, which I was sure to include as a hyperlink in my answer. By linking to that dictionary reference source, you will find definition 29a, as cited, is listed among several other definitions under the heading "IDIOMS ABOUT SO."